# Magento 2.3.4 - Product Pages

Tags: magento2, products

I'm struggling with the product pages. When I click on any book in the store, I am getting a message that says Http Error 500. It's happening on every product page.

I read that this was caused by not enough memory for the site. The .htaccess file had more memory listed than the 256MB recommended by the other sites. They also recommended renaming the .htaccess file, but when I did that, I started getting a different area of too many redirects. So I tried deleting cookies, etc, but that did nothing to help. The redirect issue went away as soon as I renamed the file back to its original name. [image]

I've attached the error page. Is this a memory problem, or is this possibly a redirect or incorrect URL problem?

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

Comment: Check php error logs on your server to find out the exact error.

Comment: The System and the Debug files in var>log.

2020-08-29 16:02:54] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-29 16:02:54] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

In reading up on these, they do not seem to be a critical server issue, though they're annoying.  I have made changes to the pnp.ini, but I need to restart my server. Is that the correct next step?